# DOM isn't updating unless it clicked on

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I have a service that gets data from a server by a simple get request,  subscribing to it from a component and assign the response to a variable in the component which is mapped to a table in the HTML. when the page loads the table  is empty and when I click anywhere in the DOM the view updates and the table loads the data

in component.ts

```
   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this.myService.searchAttendanceRecords(5, 1, 'id', 1).subscribe(res => 
       {
         console.log(res); // this works
         this.data = res;
       }
   }
```

in HTML

```
  <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th >Employee</th>
          <th >Date Time</th>
          <th >Latitude</th>
          <th >Longitude</th>
          <th>Driving</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
          <tr >
            <td data-title="Employee">{{item.Employee}}</td>
            <td data-title="Date Time">{{item.DateTime}}</td>
            <td data-title="Latitude">{{item.Latitude}}</td>
            <td data-title="Longitude">{{item.Longitude}}</td>
            <td data-title="Driving">{{item.IsDriving}}</td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>


      </tbody>
    </table>
```

expected: table loads on the page load or refresh

actual: table won't load unless I click on the DOM

Comment: I don't know what your input/output situation is but `setTimeout(()=>this.data = res,0);` will probably solve the issue.

Comment: I already tried it. It did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually caused by changeDetection.OnPush strategy.

https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4?gi=de1aeda3d62c

Please show your @Component decorator in full.

It might also be in a parent @Component decorator.

Comment: It might be, because we are using an angular theme called 'metronic' that might used changeDetection.

Comment: yes, you are right. they used it in the app.component.    @Component({
 
 selector: 'body[m-root]',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

Comment: Please mark it as an answer, if it solved your issue, so we can close this.

Comment: solved it by adding "private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef" to the component constructor then calling "this.cdr.detectChanges();" after "this.data = res;"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to subscribe under `ngOnInit` as well.

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.myService.searchAttendanceRecords(5, 1, 'id', 1).subscribe(res => 
   {
     console.log(res); // this works
     this.data = res;
   }
}
```